# How to (properly) synchronise self.Refresh() with the screen refresh to avoid blinking drawing?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to animate a 2d Object (drawn as a path), therefore it needs to be redrawn. What is the best way to redraw it without having a blinking object?

After redrawing it with `self.Refresh()` when the onIdle-Event is called, then I used a timer with a fixed time to call `self.Refresh()`, which works way better. But still I have the problem of a blinking object.

```py
import wx
import math
import time

class ObjectDrawer(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        # Initialize vars
        self.dc = None
        self.gc = None
        self.lastTime = time.time()
        super(ObjectDrawer, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        # Initialize the GUI
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.evt_timer)
        self.ShowFullScreen(True)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('white')

    def evt_timer(self, event):
        self.Refresh()

    def drawObjects(self):
        path = self.gc.CreatePath()
        #Add Something to the path e.g. a circle
        path.AddCircle(100,100,50)
        self.gc.StrokePath(path)
        path = None

    def OnPaint(self, e):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        self.gc = wx.GraphicsContext.Create(dc)
        self.gc.SetPen(wx.Pen('#e8b100', 5, wx.LONG_DASH))
        self.drawObjects()
        self.timer.Start(1000/60)


app = wx.App()
window = ObjectDrawer(None)
window.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: How do you define the path to be drawn? With your code I get UnboundLocalError: local variable 'path' referenced before assignment

Comment: @kbr85 Upps! I shortened the code too much, it should work by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `self.Refresh()` to `self.Refresh(False)` the flickering disapears. You could also use wx.AutoBufferedPaintDC instead of wx.PaintDC. Take a look at this [example](https://wiki.wxpython.org/BubblesToy) in the wxpython wiki for a more complex example.

Comment: I switched to `wx.AutoBufferedPaintDC` and after adding `self.setBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)` it works just perfect. Thank you